# Use nodejs EWS library sending email through Exchange Online is always considered as spam

Tags: node.js, email, office365, exchangewebservices

I implement an Exchange web mail client using EWS with nodejs. When I tested it by sending an email from my PC to Local Exchange server, everything was fine. All test emails were sent successfully.

But when I deployed the project on Server (VPS on Digial Ocean) and connect to Exchange Online which is part of Office365 subscription (Free Trial). The problem occurs, all emails sent from my server were considered as spam, and cannot be sent to reciepients.

I also change hosting from Digital Ocean to AWS, the result is the same.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance,

This is Diagnostic information

```
Authentication-Results: #########.com; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;########.com; dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=exzyoffice.onmicrosoft.com;
Received: from SG2PR01MB0361.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.161.11.156) by
 SG2PR01MB0362.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.161.11.16) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.1.649.16; Tue, 4 Oct
 2016 16:58:07 +0000
Received: from SG2PR01MB0361.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com ([10.161.11.156])
 by SG2PR01MB0361.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com ([10.161.11.156]) with mapi
 id 15.01.0649.022; Tue, 4 Oct 2016 16:58:07 +0000
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: ###### ######## <######@##########.onmicrosoft.com>
To: "chanyut@#########.com" <chanyut@########.com>, "chanyutx10@#####.com"
  <chanyutx10@##########.com>
Subject: Check-in PIN for Test PIN Email - Meeting System
Thread-Topic: Check-in PIN for Test PIN Email - Meeting System
Thread-Index: AQHSHmB6uwXOpaeopUqgpi/eM7C6wA==
Date: Tue, 4 Oct 2016 16:58:06 +0000
Message-ID: <SG2PR01MB03614F6A8834FDB61C01DEF2FDC50@SG2PR01MB0361.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <SG2PR01MB03614F6A8834FDB61C01DEF2FDC50@SG2PR01MB0361.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [188.166.177.7]
Return-Path: chanthat@exzyoffice.onmicrosoft.com
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 567de66e-0dff-4626-9fa1-08d3ec779d39
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
     1;SG2PR01MB0362;2:zy4eJMXvSbYZweZat1h/FneV4A2yOxpO8vpRdwEwCLWm8QipVnNdHzsBf+KyaetEsivdt7hl30XR0eCUs5T7EL7aar+e5fDuacG0fUm/7j7SH93besRmhZRaLZIup+pZYqzXKS6xnbd+kPd4Nf6gyMcfj0DL8ALLqSmf5b6aI7nuwiOIuO+z9Hw7XAD9vGMIZNSA64aw3BTeAxnxqqY1pw==;3:5BABxsk+E39PYBKVh9pWEKhIMBMLNKyOseakzwXuwPpHSiVt3bS8Ov+hYnw6Qs3Y0GMVQY0wlnaMopAEVphplwf5oy+oT5cLDIXzvg+q1GoAaeCu3TFALwH98FrKZr787qYEFnRV9pV0zqyocM+XBw==;25:ctGAmAQ1cu+BduByl6+MPAKb8/xsxaUIMq7FPDVqzTZDtsDLYREoYwbNlL10iTwrv0ON01j2DfmyRNvh6e6gL2Xcb/qjVqavMTzITJAVuBJlIHNiCgfpnW4mVNkb1dO4vJEZV6CI0KSk3RQH9Dh6/u56/zjv5ESEuuv9EQxcKYC8Mf0TJR+NHAr540/1+7h0yLDm2495YG46kfuJft6Y74HaYFiNVl/L3r31kA84l82qQez2sGGcgHo6kJv3w3QmB5garjK7j0HfceHEogOuofDJwz0Y47YfMaJg1/kyQhDGytMmQxrdJ2aRt8VcbjcKnF7Nfl3KbU/CkU33kZ9Vp3Fa9hustkf7lOD/bL1PsMSH2kOXmolb5ks1kvmF1hZ+pTsNzd0Zz9mNuErtxp7lK5hMfNL+NeLnAjnRZfvqX6/JK4ZRr7IlPw/YSvmMMxPM
X-Microsoft-Antispam: UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:SG2PR01MB0362;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
        1;SG2PR01MB0362;31:GR+rFHTjFRwfnJTe4nsRPGyP0mSyV+kDu/elZc5VaNeIXHm90HhmKo5Bzt08Yg9rKmPGkbTp2OVLPv8WIMt0ssqobSrA4ZGc44yBtlqefEAI18SF76/RrOxzmXDwUX82fkrubNc2e6IVrlDWQ0HO5cc1AYbatOZEwAfe3OzBg9rhw+u3ef8oBU5E++bzAqdqL0n/o+TrnEhy18ZJrL14yIhXEYsy159STM7O4Szj4pxh02al5tcE0CrpzdET9Wxo;4:0g+YEprdQNgkE9AkEVGWN/VFqIpOq92oDR1yeXN1yQeuGkHuWB6I9KIZSMLZHsjKildUXRPySE/Wv/r61w8hqbz0goIrlvYrEg+tCTDjM/0IsdxhXnGcsmgLIXAu4PRoTlkejJlaNqwtHqT217nzBDlCVu7E/4LwAPUpSk6+wQZhjAUfG/v3t3PNCHpL7hEsaK/KkqyKuJ+TbybDB5D+/JmqfQpzvxsP7pIOntHQmwbakW6g/I474q6I6x34yzVHOsA8tP/70Y6NbpA3P6hAOIh8ioFswLPAKbc/rO3q4pcAyARvVyXmNh6NeVntO1SaFUxqCn9OZSVWN3/pK3rVLDCHDkHisckt4VSGcN54vQcYR79Cod5jgMSjA2aMTtY8wPYf1ZxbU67WgCk9XJ8dpIceUZzF7cxZs78fr5kY7q9IMaYciZB7zR4v2Ds0pdmP36iITdLNHXdxOaqt3gY2g3oktTguQ87whqzg6+RJrO8=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS:
     <SG2PR01MB036291996D70C36ABCD297ECFDC50@SG2PR01MB0362.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: UriScan:;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:
     BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(6040176)(601004)(2401047)(8121501046)(5005006)(10201501046)(3002001)(6002118)(6000006)(6043046)(6042046);SRVR:SG2PR01MB0362;
X-Forefront-PRVS: 00851CA28B
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
   1;SG2PR01MB0362;23:SGkU+hCO1Me9ul5A85nokDETPc2fvnqIJBuMSsUaizPW5SU30hQ/9h8FERIrUfQlyhOSjKXtfJtRPa7dctubpraPm8t+7i1Tu9MmC3xqJss5m9gdTncr4lcByV677Os8wLvADH/SnogL/EucwxkzNm2M2WVwLpE2sOw9ochCbZuAMN2CQT+XKJnuSefgwHo8tfCdYWSEVRE3gleOfPWMTtYERp11xjY4NRCqU9WTcPLq6OMA+LIwdc8D0wpEPF++UgSfYeQ5Rd+SKnXW/++ZWw==;6:YwRMvgBmAN1rsxVOfmcL8JnjlX63xYoEQRiiRNoehWPk1+mB8M2XiRWLtmuHBVuOmi0CUeuQXuFWGEIS+Z1q8u0ARqjLoVkjHjTsZUMeiliHUg4bNAZfZdZNL2JRsp6zrdY+xNotdkzKO1+QN+yUV5USrfMLPo3eX8p/XAsvCB2MUikXyUyv9Lwpp71jzDsLExLz+AkKi2JKAxquPePw3OyzITh/BEpnxnRBVVAAKwOLg0cdxtcHNFiztVLcHSdqs6ygXQftAh+CbSqWlKLwkXitOLDdwbXVo2RYvT3DDC+8CYyoab8sRGihjxfbFw3M
```